# Restore enum field values

Tags: enums, mysqlbinlog, mysql-backup

I changed possible values from a enum field from a mysql table. I think with this change some values from changed field were lost. 
Is it possible somehow to restore these values? I have a mysqlbinlog for DB changes.

Thanks

Comment: Depends on what you changed and when and what's happened since and if you have some audit trail. Possible yes, probable, well who knows.

Comment: The changes were made few hours ago, I just removed some values from list of permitted enum values. mysqlbinlog is for tracking the changes from DB.

Comment: Afrid I dont know, whether simply altering the enum, to put them back will repair it. Restoring teh back up from just before y9ou did would.. I jhad one go with enums when I first bumped into MySQl, decided they were more trouble than they were worth and never bothered with them again.